# The third derivative of the first principles definition of of a derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

So the $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ this is what I learned to find the first derivative and by taking this concept and trying to find the second derivative using this method I came up with this : $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ (All divided by h, I wasn't sure how to do that on here).

Now, I've only tried using this formula with x^3 and it worked fine.

My question is how would I do the third derivative? 
This is what I came up with but it doesn't work out. If any one has any ideas how I would come up with this then that would be awesome. Basically what I'm trying to do is find the formula that leads to finding the third derivative of a function using the derivative definition. Thanks!

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+3h)-f(x+2h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ (All divided by h once again)

Comment: Your question has been answered and you have accepted an answer. It is only fair to those who have spent time answering it if you leave it as-is and ask another question, rather than changing this one.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that limit can exist even if $f$ is not three-times differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this expression for second derivative, then
$f'''(x) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+3h) - f(x+2h)}{h^3} - 2\frac{f(x+2h) - f(x+h)}{h^3} + \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h^3} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+3h)-3f(x+2h)+3f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^3}$

Comment: Note that this assumes the existence of $f'''(x)$. So this can't be taken as a definition, but rather a formula for $f'''(x)$ if one knows beforehand that $f'''(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 4):

Your 2nd and 3rd derivative definitions are wrong.

The correct definition of derivative of a function $f(x)$ is the following:
$$ f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

To get 2nd derivative order you should apply the definition of derivative on the function $f'(x)$.
$$
f''(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(x+h) - f'(x)}{h}$$

to have the 3rd derivative $f'''(x)$ use the definition of derivative and apply it to $f''(x)$.