# 2 Problems about Residue Theorem, Laurent Expansion.

Tags: complex-analysis

1.$f$ is holomorphic on $0<|z|<2$.

$\forall z\in\mathbb N, f(\frac{1}{n})=n^2, f(-\frac{1}{n})=n^3$.

What kind of singularity does $f$ have at $0$ (origin)?

For this problem, I tried Laurent expansion around $z=0$, but I couldn't get any meaningful result.

2.$f$ is holomorphic on $|z|<1$.

$f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{7}{n^3}$ for $n=2,3,4,...$

Find $f'''(0)$.

For the second problem, I easily know that the answer is 42 if I think $f(z)=7z^3$ but I know it's not enough. How could I say about other $f$ which satisfies the condition? I tried Taylor expansion around $z=0$, $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+..., f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{7}{2^3}...$

And I realized that the first problem and the second problem have something in common. But how could I proceed further?

Thank you for reading.

EDIT: Is it okay if I use identity theorem to the second problem, so that the function which satisfies the condition is only $f(z)=7z^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards the second problem, note that $f(0)=0$ and
$$f'''(0) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(3h)-3f(2h)+3f(h)-f(0)}{h^3}$$
Now take $h=\frac{1}{6n}$, and 
$$f'''(0) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(1/(2n))-3f(1/(3n))+3f(1/(6n))}{1/(6n)^3}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}42=42.$$
We can also use the [Identity Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem): if the function $f$ is holomorphic in a connected subset $\Omega\in\mathbb{C}$ and $(z_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\Omega$ with an accumulation point in $\Omega$ and $f(z_n)=0$, then $f$ is identically zero. Therefore here $f(z)=7z^3$ and $f'''(0)=42$.

For the first question, can $0$ be a [pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis)) of $f$?

Comment: How can $f'''(0)$ be expressed that way? I definitely saw that kind of transformation somewhere but I forgot. Can you teach me any keyword in order for me to search? And How about the method I mentioned in the EDIT above that I use identity theorem to get $f(z)=7z^3$?

Comment: See for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308366/the-third-derivative-of-the-first-principles-definition-of-of-a-derivative

Comment: As regards your approach, yes $f(z)=7z^3$, because the difference $f(z)-7z^3$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1$, and it vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point $0$, therefore it is identically zero. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511718/when-a-holomorphic-function-is-identically-0

Comment: If $0$ is a pole, the principal part of laurent expansion has to have finite terms. Or equivalently, $\lim_{z\to 0}|f(z)|=\infty.$ It seems that $\lim_{z\to 0}|f(z)|=\infty$ if I think $f(\frac{1}{n})=n^2, f(-\frac{1}{n})=n^3$, but I'm not sure because, considering $z\to0$ approaching in other directions, I can't tell that $\lim_{z\to 0}|f(z)|=\infty.$ Furthermore, if $0$ is a pole, how can I find the order?

Comment: As I think again now, It seems that it's not a pole because I can't decide the order of the pole. (2 or 3)

Comment: @Arbitrary Yes, you are correct.